# Bash script error: integer expression expected

Tags: bash

I'm having a rather weird issue, I'm running a script (Bash) on multiple servers and it stopped working on one of the servers (works perfectly fine on all other servers).

Here is the problem part of the script: (I did not write it myself, all credits go to "Rich") (http://www.notrainers.org/monitoring-memory-usage-on-linux-with-nagios-and-nrpe/)

```
    if [ "$result" -lt "$warn_level" ]; then     #Line 56
    echo "Memory OK. $result% used."
    exit 0;
elif [ "$result" -ge "$warn_level" ] && [ "$result" -le "$critical_level" ]; then  #Line 59
    echo "Memory WARNING. $result% used."
    exit 1;
elif [ "$result" -gt "$critical_level" ]; then   #Line 62
    echo "Memory CRITICAL. $result% used."
    exit 2;
fi
```

Complete error message:

```
./check_memory.sh: Line 56: [: 7.: integer expression expected

./check_memory.sh: Line 59: [: 7.: integer expression expected

./check_memory.sh: Line 62: [: 7.: integer expression expected
```

If you need more info, let me know and I will try to supply it as fast as possible.

Appreciate all inputs :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the link you provided, I see the below line.

```
result=$(echo "$used / $total * 100" |bc -l|cut -c -2)
```

As per @Graeme's comment, change the above line to below.

```
result=$(echo "$used / $total * 100" |bc -l)
```

Now, after adding the above line, we have to change the output of the `result` to integer as below.

```
result1=${result/.*}
```

I guess in one of the machines where the error occurs, this output is not an integer. Just convert the output of result to integer so that you can handle such cases. Add the below line after you calculate the `result`.

```
result1=${result/.*}
```

And instead of `result` change the variable names as `result1` inside the `if` loops, and the error won't occur.

I suspect, the `cut -c -2` attributes to the error mostly since it is cutting the first 2 characters only. What if result has just one character? Suppose if result is `1.23456`, the above cut will result in `1.` as the value for `result` which obviously is the cause of the `integer expected` error.

The reason it is working fine in the remaining servers is because it has not encountered a case where the `result` variable has just a single digit. It is highly likely to fail in the remaining servers too if the result is a single digit variable (something like I mentioned in the above example).

Comment: `${result%%.*}` would be the correct expansion to remove the decimal point here. But note that the `cut -c -2` will also cause issues with numbers of 100 or more, so it is safer to drop it completely.

Comment: @Graeme, I missed that. I should have made the changes in that line :)

Answer (score 6):

By the look of things, your `result` variable has a `.` in it after the number making bash not recognise it as such. You can reproduce the error by simply doing:

```
[ 7. -gt 1 ]
```

If you add more of the script to your question, |I can suggest where this might be coming from.

#### Update

Looking at the full script, I would just replace the line:

```
result=$(echo "$used / $total * 100" |bc -l|cut -c -2)
```

With:

```
result=$(( 100 * used / total ))
```

Since `used` and `total` are integers and `bash` does integer arithmetic, though note the shifting of the multiplication be 100 to the beginning. Or if you want to ensure correct rounding ('integer division' in computing always effectively rounds down):

```
result=$( printf '%.0f' $(echo "$used / $total * 100" | bc -l) )
```

This will ensure that there are no trailing dots in `result`. The approach using `cut` is not a very good idea since it is only valid for result in the range 10-99. It will fail for a `result` from 0-9 (as in your case) and also numbers above 99.

#### Update 2

From [@Stephane's comment below](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122993/bash-script-error-integer-expression-expected/122994?noredirect=1#comment194974_122994), you are better to round down when comparing to thresholds. Considering this, there is another small error with the snippet in the question - notice the inconsistency between the comparisons used for the `warn_level` and the `critical_level`. The comparisons for `warn_level` are correct, but `critical_level` uses `-le` (lesser or equal) instead of `-lt` (just lesser). Consider when `result` is slightly larger than `critical_level` - it will be rounded down to `critical_level` and not trigger the critical warning even though it should (and would if a `-lt` comparison was used).

Perhaps not much of an issue, but here is the corrected code:

```
if [ "$result" -lt "$warn_level" ]; then
  echo "Memory OK. $result% used."
  exit 0;
elif [ "$result" -lt "$critical_level" ]; then
  echo "Memory WARNING. $result% used."
  exit 1;
else
  echo "Memory CRITICAL. $result% used."
  exit 2;
fi
```

The `-ge` tests are also redundant since these cases are implied on reaching the `elif`/`else`, so have been removed.

Comment: However, to check against thresholds, you don't want to round _up_. 49.6 should still be _OK_ if the warning threshold is 50. So `result=$(( 100 * $used / $total ))` should be just fine.

Answer (score 0):

So I don't know how to use `awk` very well at all. But I do know that what's going on in the script you linked is a lot of nonsense and that something like the following should work. I'm sorry I can't write this out perfectly well, but since you're already calling `awk` - twice it seems - you should be using something like this.

```
_chkmem() { return $( 
    free -m | grep "buffers/cache"
        awk '{ 
        percent = ( $3 / ( $3 + $4 ) ) * 100     
        warn = '"${warnlevel?No warning level specified!}"' < percent ? WARNING : OK
        crit = '"${critical?No critical level specified!}"' < percent ? CRITICAL : $warn
        print "Mem $crit : $percent% used"
        if ( $crit != OK ) exit 1
    }')
}

_chkmem || exit 1
```